# Parallel data to file

Tags: unix, parallel-port, dot-matrix-printer

this question is about catching printer data and writing it in a file.

We use an old Unix system which is unfortunately crucial. This Unix system uses a matrix printer. This printer seems to get its driver from Unix and it happens often that the printer has failures and we have to reboot both the unix machine and the printer. We do not want to configure too much on the Unix machine.
I am thinking of using paralell->USB and letting an other computer catch the file and store it. Advantage is also that I have the data digital in stead of on rows of paper
Or maybe it is possible using the parallel->usb cable and placing it to an usb printer

Somebody knows if this is possible? If yes, please give me a clue

Many thanks

Ben de Boer

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you do the printing, you could use the "`tee`" command as follows:

```
cat myprinteddoc.txt | tee 'catchprintout.txt' > /dev/prn
```

What the tee command does is to write its input to a file and also output it. Check Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I think this is not what we would like to do. I really would like to avoid to change something on this Unix machine. I rather grab the output Unix generates via the parallel cable and do something with this.